# correct JSONP Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm trying locally to get JSONP to give me a correct response and pass it into my callback function jsonp_callback. Using code from: [How do I set up JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519209/how-do-i-set-up-jsonp)

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$data = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5); 
echo $_GET['jsonpCallback'] . '('.json_encode($data).')';
```

and

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'jsonp-response.php', 
    dataType:'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
    success: function (r){
        console.log(r);
    }
});


function jsonp_callback (r){
    console.log('jsonp_callback:',r);
}
```

Sofar I'm getting a Response which looks like:

```
jQuery1102035954900085926056_1381230228656({"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5})
```

Looking at the first answer from [Testing a static jsonp response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373419/testing-a-static-jsonp-response) I think I'm doing it correctly but I'm not sure why jQuery gives me a unique string.

How would I make my response look like this ?

```
jsonp_callback({"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5})
```

Comment: Is it possible that your response is a string as opposed to a JSON object? Can you check it?

Comment: the success function returns an object

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read your initial post. I see it now. I'm not familiar with setting the `jsonp` property, but did you try the following in the `success` property? `success: function (r){ jsonp_callback(r); }`

Comment: including jsonp_callback(r) into success would work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the snippets from my code.. If it solves your problems..

## Client Code :

Set jsonpCallBack : 'photos' and dataType:'jsonp'

```
 $('document').ready(function() {
            var pm_url = 'http://localhost:8080/diztal/rest/login/test_cor?sessionKey=4324234';
            $.ajax({
                crossDomain: true,
                url: pm_url,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'photos'
            });
        });
        function photos (data) {
            alert(data);
            $("#twitter_followers").html(data.responseCode);
        };
```

## Server Side Code (Using Rest Easy)

```
@Path("/test_cor")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String testCOR(@QueryParam("sessionKey") String sessionKey, @Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
    ResponseJSON<LoginResponse> resp = new ResponseJSON<LoginResponse>();
    resp.setResponseCode(sessionKey);
    resp.setResponseText("Wrong Passcode");
    resp.setResponseTypeClass("Login");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return "photos("+gson.toJson(resp)+")"; // CHECK_THIS_LINE
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'jsonp-response.php', 
    dataType:'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
    success: jsonp_callback 
});

function jsonp_callback (r) {
    console.log('jsonp_callback:',r);
}
```

In your code you never actually used the `jsonp_callback` function that you defined. You simply wrote some anonymous success callback. jQuery noticed that you used an anonymous function and that's why it generated this random name so that it can invoke the anonymous callback.

Comment: Yes that passes into the function jsonp_callback.

The response in the header still looks like `jQuery11020983548907097429_1381238805774({"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5})`